# Trying to change a value in a FOR LOOP for ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java

In the code below I have a ByteArrayOutputStream that I'm trying to loop through and the objective is trying to REPLACE the HTML equivalent of & with the "&" character itself. The issue that I'm trying to correct is that the HTML value is being printed in a log and I need to correct that with "&". The code where this is being printed in my log is below and is what I've attempted but this is NOT working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final PrintStream pStream = new PrintStream(baos);
receivedIsoMessage.dumpMsg(pStream, "Message received:");
for (final String logString : baos.toString().split("\n")) {
    if (baos.toString().contains("&amp;")) {
        logString.replace("&amp;", "&");
    }
    LOGGER.info(logString.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", ""));
}
```

Comment: is it throwing a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: No. It just maintains the "&amp;" value.

Comment: you don't need the `if` statement.  you can call `replace` on the string even if the string to search for doesn't exist

Comment: Am I the only one wondering why the baos.toString() method is used in the if statement instead of logString?

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace()` returns a new String but you are discarding it.

Try this instead

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final PrintStream pStream = new PrintStream(baos);
receivedIsoMessage.dumpMsg(pStream, "Message received:");
for (String logString : baos.toString().split("\n")) {
    if (baos.toString().contains("&amp;")) {
        logString = logString.replace("&amp;", "&");
    }
    LOGGER.info(logString.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", ""));
}
```

**EDIT**: As noted in the comments, this code has some unnecessary checks and could be simplified.  For example, the entire for loop can be replaced by a single line:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final PrintStream pStream = new PrintStream(baos);
receivedIsoMessage.dumpMsg(pStream, "Message received:");

LOGGER.info(baos.toString().replaceAll("&amp;", "&").replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", ""));
```

Comment: Why didnt u change the if statement? It makes no sense for me to check every time if the whole input has that value and therefore if it exists, use the replace method on every line. (even if some lines dont have that value)

Comment: @Ben Agreed, the `if (baos.toString().contains("&amp;"))` is redundant.  However I was trying to change as little code as possible to make it easier to see the necessary change.

Answer (score 1):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

final PrintStream pStream = new PrintStream(baos);
receivedIsoMessage.dumpMsg(pStream, "Message received:");
for (String logString : baos.toString().split("\n")) {
    if (logString.contains("&amp;")) { // or just remove the if statement like Sam mentioned
        logString = logString.replace("&amp;", "&");
    }
    LOGGER.info(logString.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", ""));
}
```

1. You forgot to assign the result from the replace method to logString
2. That was not possible since you declared it as final

Answer (score 1):

Java Strings are immutable.

```
logString.replace("&amp;", "&");
```

does nothing. Try

```
String newString=logString.replace("&amp;", "&");
LOGGER.info(newString.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", ""));
```

Comment: @Ben your implementation creates a new `String` object too

Comment: @Ben Sam is right. A new string will be created in all cases.

Comment: Ouch. Seems not like my day - ofc you guys are right. I was just confused why you didnt use logString. Sry for the noise ;)

Comment: Basically there are 2 reasons: 1. change as less as possible the original Melinda’s code; 2. Make the code more readable